# Remove linefeed from csv preserving rows

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a CSV that was exported, some lines have a linefeed (ASCII 012) in the middle of a record. I need to replace this with a space, but preserve the new line for each record to load it.

Most of the lines are fine, however a good few have this:

Input:

```
10 , ,"2007-07-30 13.26.21.598000" ,1922 ,0 , , , ,"Special Needs List Rows updated :
Row 1 : Instruction: other :Comment: pump runs all of the water for the insd's home" ,10003 ,524 ,"cc:2023" , , ,2023 , , ,"CCR" ,"INSERT" ,"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555" ,"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"
```

Output:

```
10 , ,"2007-07-30 13.26.21.598000" ,1922 ,0 , , , ,"Special Needs List Rows updated :Row 1 : Instruction: other :Comment: pump runs all of the water for the insd's home" ,10003 ,524 ,"cc:2023" , , ,2023 , , ,"CCR" ,"INSERT" ,"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555" ,"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"
```

I have been looking into Awk but cannot really make sense of how to preserve the actual row.

Another Example:

Input:

```
9~~"2007-08-01 16.14.45.099000"~2215~0~~~~"Exposure closed (Unnecessary) : Garage door working
Claim Withdrawn"~~701~"cc:6007"~~564~6007~~~"CCR"~"INSERT"~"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"~"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"
4~~"2007-08-01 16.14.49.333000"~1923~0~~~~"Assigned to user Leanne Hamshere in group GIO Home Processing (Team 3)"~~912~"cc:6008"~~~6008~~~"CCR"~"INSERT"~"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"~"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"
```

Output:

```
9~~"2007-08-01 16.14.45.099000"~2215~0~~~~"Exposure closed (Unnecessary) : Garage door working Claim Withdrawn"~~701~"cc:6007"~~564~6007~~~"CCR"~"INSERT"~"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"~"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"
4~~"2007-08-01 16.14.49.333000"~1923~0~~~~"Assigned to user Leanne Hamshere in group GIO Home Processing (Team 3)"~~912~"cc:6008"~~~6008~~~"CCR"~"INSERT"~"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"~"2011-12-03 01.25.39.759555"
```

Comment: Doing this reliably requires a tools that recognize CSV formats (and variants judging from the tilde-separated example) that will allow you to pick out the fields that are spread over two or more lines and replace the newlines with blanks before rewriting.  I'd nominate Perl and the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) module as an appropriate tool to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "[,~]"
}

NF < 21 {
    line = (line ? line OFS : line) $0
    fields = fields + NF
}

fields >= 21 {
    print line
    line=""
    fields=0
}

NF == 21 {
    print
}
```

Alternatively, you can use this one-liner:

```
awk -F "[,~]" 'NF < 21 { line = (line ? line OFS : line) $0; fields = fields + NF } fields >= 21 { print line; line=""; fields=0 } NF == 21 { print }' file.txt
```

---

Explanation:

I made an observation about your expected output: it seems each line should contain exactly 21 fields. Therefore if your line contains less than 21 fields, store the line and store the number of fields. When we loop onto the next line, the line will be joined to the stored line with a space, and the number of fields totaled. If this number of fields is greater or equal to 21 (the sum of the fields of a broken line will add to 22), print the stored line. Else if the line contains 21 fields (NF == 21), print it. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

I think `sed` is your choice. I assume all the records end with non-colon character, thus if a line end with a colon, it is recognized as an exception and should be concatenated to the previous line.

Here is the code:

```
cat data | sed -e '/[^"]$/N' -e 's/\n//g'
```

The first execution `-e '/[^"]$/N'` match an abnormal case, and read in next record without empty the buffer. Then `-e 's/\n//g'` remove the new line character.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the line above, but they are not always ended with a non-colon. It can be any character unfortunately.

Comment: You're welcome. But any other patterns in your case? e.g. The broken line starts with a word(`Row`, etc.), while normally lines begin with line numbers(`10` in the example)? If you want to use `awk` you'd better summarize sufficient patterns.

Answer (score 2):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '{if(t){print;t=0;next;}x=$0;n=gsub(/"/,"",x);if(n%2){printf $0" ";t=1;}else print $0}' file
```

idea:
count the number of `"` in a line. if the count is odd, join the following line, otherwise the current line would be considered as a complete line.