# How can I bring multiline data in quotes back into one line?

Tags: regex, bash, csv, sed, awk

I have a csv file which looks like this. Please note, that not all data entries are multiline!

```
225253;abc;def;ghi;"- sometext 
- sometext
- 3sometext
";asd,asd;58.2500;False;False;False;17;0.0000;;
```

My goal is to use a bash script in order to convert it into this form:

```
225253;abc;def;ghi;"- sometext - sometext - 3sometext";asd,asd;58.2500;False;False;False;17;0.0000;;
```

My first guess was this. But somehow it won't work...

```
sed -e 's/\"\([^"]+\)\"//g'
```

Comment: Related question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11024245/1258041

Comment: So the file has multiple entries; some of those entries are split over multiple lines, others are not; and the number of lines can vary, I imagine.  That's gonna be tricky; you really need a tool that understands CSV.  I'd suggest Perl and [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV); Python also has support for CSV.

Comment: Yeah, choose your favourite "get-stuff-done" language -- Perl, Python, Ruby, whatever -- and use its `csv` tools instead.

Answer (score 1):

The clean way to do this is using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm), as [@JonathanLeffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) suggested in comments, or something equivalent to that. That is, using a library dedicated to processing CSV files. See my Perl implementation at the bottom.

However, `Text::CSV` is usually not installed by default, so you might have to install it yourself. If that's not an option or too difficult for you, then a less perfect but simpler `awk` solution might be good enough, based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574911/remove-linefeed-from-csv-preserving-rows):

```
awk -F ";" -v nf=13 'NF < nf { line = line (line ? OFS : "") $0; fields += NF } fields >= nf { print line; line=""; fields=0 } NF == nf'
```

For reference, the Perl solution using `Text::CSV`:

```
use Text::CSV;

my $sep = ';';
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, sep_char => $sep });

while (my $row = $csv->getline(*STDIN)) {
    print join($sep, map { s/\n$//; s/ *\n/ /g; $_ } @$row), "\n";
}
```

Save this in a file `transform-csv.pl` and run it with:

```
perl transform-csv.pl < sample.csv
```

Comment: thanks for the code. unfortunatly the code only deletes the first 1-2 line breaks. When there is data which goes through 20 lines it doesn't work. =(

Comment: @user3084928 I improved my answer. If it still doesn't work, please edit your question and add a better sample so I can test.

Comment: have you noticed the brackets? `" "` maybe there is a way to delete them and everything in between. I don't need the data inside the brackets. =)

Comment: @user3084928 I don't understand what you mean... And in any case, can't your finish on your own from here?

Comment: it seems to be a bit tricky... `Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at transform-csv.pl line 1.`

Comment: Yeah, it's usually not installed by default, you have to install it using the package manager of your operating system. In which OS are you?

Comment: Found the solution here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574911/remove-linefeed-from-csv-preserving-rows)
`awk -F "[,~]" 'NF < 21 { line = (line ? line OFS : line) $0; fields = fields + NF } fields >= 21 { print line; line=""; fields=0 } NF == 21 { print }' file.txt`

Comment: @user3084928 Nice one. I rewrote my solution, using an improved version of this script you linked.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/^[^"]*("[^"]*")+(;[^"]+|$)/b;$!{N;s/\n//;ba}' file
```

This looks for lines with matching quotes. If it finds a line with non-matching quotes it appends the next line removes the newline and repeats until the quotes match or reaches the end of the file.

N.B. This does not cater for quotes within quotes.

Comment: This deletes all line breaks, but not only line breaks between brackets. =/

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS -e'my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary=>1,sep_char=>";"});while(my $row = $csv->getline(ARGV)){$csv->print(STDOUT,[map s/\n/ /g,@$row])}'
```

or you can use `Text::CSV` as well. Add parameters to parser constructor for tuning other behavior.

Comment: how do I call the csv file in this perl script?

Comment: @user3084928 I don't understand what do you mean by _call the csv file_

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/\n/,"")}1' FS=";" RS=";" ORS=";" file
```

gives

```
225253;abc;def;ghi;"- sometext - sometext- sometext";asd,asd;58.2500;False;False;False;17;0.0000;;
```

**Update**

Or using `patsplit` in Gnu Awk version 4:

```
BEGIN { FS=RS=";"}
{
    if (patsplit($0,a,/"[^"]+"/,s)) {
        gsub(/\n/,"",a[1])
        printf "%s%s%s", s[0],a[1],s[1]
    }
    else
        printf "%s", $0
    printf ";"
}
```

This will only remove newlines inside double quotes..

Comment: This deletes all line breaks, but not only line breaks between brackets. =/

Comment: @user3084928 Oh, I see you do not just want a single line of output.. It is then only line breaks within double quotes that should be removed?

Comment: okay that looks great! Could you please just help me to syntax into a bash script where I call the sourcefile?

Comment: @user3084928 Great! Just save the script to a file `a.awk`. Then in bash script use: `awk -f a.awk file`..

Answer (score 0):

Can also try this sed script. It matches lines which have open double quote `"` without field separator `;` before end of line. Assuming that you need to remove newlines only if they occur within double quoted fields. It also assumes that whole field is quoted (at least ends like `"stuff";`). If that's not the case then slight adjustment shall be made.

```
:again
/"[^;]*$/ {
  N
  s/\n//
  b again
}
s/"[^;]*";/;/g
```

put it into `script.sed` and run like `sed -r -f script.sed file`

If quoted fields shall be retained then just delete last line from the script.

Comment: works pretty fine, but it always only deletes ONE linebreak. Reason, the stupid guys really have `;` in the brackets too!! *pureanger* ;) But there are several between the brackets. =/

Comment: So I have experimented with some regex and the following is working fine. But somehow it doesn't work wird sed. Any syntax clues? `[\;][\"]([^"][^;]*)[\"][\;]`

Comment: If you could paste more source data, especially lines which fail, that would be great. It is extremely difficult to guess what other tricks are contained in your data :). Wrt last question please paste the full context: how exactly do you call the sed with that regex, what is the error and which source data line(s) produce a failure or do not work as expected.